# spaces are replaced by '+' in a Link in php

Tags: php, html

I have a value in variable as follows...

```
$variable = "chicken soup.jpg";
```

when i do the following, spaces are converted to a + symbol in the output

```
$body = "www.abc.com/" . $variable
mail($to, $subject, $body,$headers)
```

> Output in mail received: **www.abc.com/chicken+soup.jpg**

But i want the output as below ? Please help

> Expected Output : www.abc.com/chicken%20soup.jpg or
>   www.abc.com/chicken soup.jpg

i tried using **str_replace** function but no luck

Comment: it's to be `$variable = "chicken soup.jpg";`

Comment: What do you mean by 'working properly'? What is your expected output?

Comment: and you're missing semicolons.

Comment: the + sign is the url encoding, since white spaces cannot be present on urls

Comment: @TobiasSpringer : i have corrected the question... please see now

Comment: @dAm2K : I want it should be coming as it is in variable.. so that i can send proper email. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure, if your email-client supports to view the plain source of that message, you'll se that the url is `"www.abc.com/chicken soup.jpg"`; only your browser / email client encodes it, as it's an invalid URL.

If you want to produce a valid url, encode it manually with:

```
$body = 'www.abc.com/' . urlencode( $variable );
// this will be 'www.abc.com/chicken+soup.jpg' as this is a valid url
```

or:

```
$body = 'www.abc.com/' . rawurlencode( $variable );
// this will be 'www.abc.com/chicken%20soup.jpg'
```

**Edit**:

You can read more about the difference:

- RFC 3986 encoding ([`rawurlencode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php))
- `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (or form post) encoding ([`urlencode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php))

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is to use `urlencode()` on the filename variable. This will convert spaces and other non-URL-friendly characters into %20 et al so that it can be used as part of a valid URL.

**Example**:

```
$variable = urlencode("chicken soup.jpg"); echo $variable;
```

**Output**:

```
chicken%20soup.jpg
```

Check the the **[urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)** documentation for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This is because all urls are encoded. It may be your E-Mail client recieves 'chicken soup.jpg' but parses it as an url and so it gets 'chicken+soup.jpg' as ' ' in urls are not valid.

Comment: How should i correct it ? i mean, I want it should be coming as it is in variable.. so that i can send proper email.

Comment: This is proper .. with spaces it's wrong, with '+' its correct.

Comment: www.abc.com/chicken+soup.jpg is not working in Browser...
www.abc.com/chicken soup.jpg is working in browser...

Comment: Yeah, but `www.abc.com/chicken soup.jpg` wont work too - because the file "chicken soup.jpg" does not exist on the server

Comment: Please dont put down vote
when you enter www.abc.com/chicken soup.jpg in browser it will automatically convert to www.abc.com/chicken%20soup.jpg